# What is the best way to call java methods from a running jar from node.js?

Tags: java, node.js

I have a jar that is continuously running as a sort of server and I want to call methods from node.js using javascript. For example let's say I have a method called `public String concatinateStrings(String[] stuff)`, how can I call this method from a node server? The method is an example, not something that I need to do in javascript.

Comment: Unless your sort of server is an actual server, you don't. If it is an actual server, then you expose that method as an endpoint. What kind of answer do you expect someone to provide based on your method name? Java is (almost) completely unrelated to JavaScript. In **fact**, JavaScript is ***officially*** named Ecmascript (a name that is a perfect compromise, **everyone hates** it - the name that is).

Comment: Yes, my question is how to expose an endpoint

Comment: Any response would have helped. After a couple more days of research I found a node package that does what I need, `node-java`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a node package called `node-java` that does what I need it to: https://github.com/joeferner/node-java